# What could be causing longer run times for a movie recommendation system on Google Cloud Platform CPU with more workers added?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I have been experimenting with the performance of a movie recommendation system on Google Cloud Platform CPU by adjusting the number of nodes and workers. Specifically, I tested two configurations: a Single Node (1 master (2 vCPU), ZERO workers) and a Standard configuration (1 master (1 vCPU), SEVEN workers (1 vCPU each)).

However, I found that adding extra resources in the form of additional worker nodes with 1 vCPU actually resulted in longer running times for the recommendation system. The results I obtained were:

Single Node (1 master (2 vCPU), ZERO workers):

- Run 1 total time: 112.98s
- Run 2 total time: 134.06s
- Run 3 total time: 117.13s

Standard (1 master (1 vCPU), SEVEN workers (1 vCPU each)):

- Run 1 total time: 160.15s
- Run 2 total time: 17617s
- Run 3 total time: 166.02s

I'm confused as to why the addition of extra workers did not lead to a decrease in running time. What could be causing this unexpected behavior?

Comment: What type of cluster were you running? Local, standalone, yarn, kubernetes, ...? Can you share the [spark configurations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) you were using for these jobs?

Comment: It was a yarn cluster.